# Openvpn client doesn't connect

Tags: openvpn, client, timeout

I'm something noobie on linux. Sorry if this question is so basic, but couldn't find a solution anywhere...

I have a windows10 host machine with Virtualbox installed.

There are two guest machines: one Windows7 and other Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3.

There is a VPN wich I want to connect the guests machine using openvpn. Both guest machines were configured using the same .ovpn config file.

When I connect via windows7 machine it connects and works perfectly. When I connect via Ubuntu, it seems that will connect, the switch of the network config screen turns orange (on), but after about a minute, there is a message on the top of the screen that says " VPN Connection Failed" and the switch turns back to gray (off).

No reason was displayed at the screen, so I looked for the logs via

grep VPN /var/log/syslog

But can't find any help for the reason. This was the output (if I can attach it as a file I think ti would be a somethig more organizated):

```
Aug 14 11:24:35 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792675.5731] keyfile: add connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SCVPN_Oficial-a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c (a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial")
Aug 14 11:24:35 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792675.5761] audit: op="connection-add" uuid="a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c" name="SCVPN_Oficial" pid=4548 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792679.5181] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c" name="SCVPN_Oficial" pid=4548 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792679.5317] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 6628
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792679.5483] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792679.6750] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792679.6752] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS nm-openvpn[6634]: WARNING: file '/home/vinicius/Oficial_Starcamp_VPN/<certificate_file_name_here>.key' is group or others accessible
Aug 14 11:24:39 WMS nm-openvpn[6634]: OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Aug 14 11:24:43 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792683.4375] audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="78f77d40-f5ce-4491-8358-1e2b53fd5782" name="SCVPN_Oficial" pid=4548 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 14 11:25:40 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <warn>  [1565792740.1467] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Aug 14 11:25:40 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <warn>  [1565792740.1515] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Aug 14 11:25:40 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792740.1517] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Aug 14 11:25:40 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792740.1518] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Aug 14 11:25:40 WMS NetworkManager[587]: <info>  [1565792740.1553] vpn-connection[0x555efa462390,a823c733-585b-4b36-96e2-a8c99a35c62c,"SCVPN_Oficial",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

There is a timeout information but I can't figure out the reason.

Looking for more information or a solution I tryed to start th VPN via command line:

```
sudo openvpn --config SCVPN_Oficial.ovpn --verb 10 > conn.log
```

After a while of no response I sent a ^C. The log produced is below (remote IP obfuscated).

Does someone have any idea what I shoud try?

Comment: It will take about a hundred comments like this to post all the log... :-( Should I?

Comment: Paste the logs onto paste.ubuntu.com or a Github Gist and then provide the link here in comments to the full logs.

Comment: Thanks for your tip Thomas. The past lik is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4p3MSsVqBs/

Answer (score 0):

Could be permissions on install of the OpenVPN Linux client? as it was NOT creating a **TUN**.
So [I made one myself](https://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces) (that was the actual issue):

```
ip tuntap add name tun0 mode tun
ip link show
```

If your version of `ip` does not support `tuntap` use `tunctl` as per:
https://serverfault.com/a/347900

source: https://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces

Alternative solution to try official openvpn3-linux client & installer that should do the config for you: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux
has very useful debug commands for you to try e.g:

```
openvpn3-admin version --services
openvpn3 config-import --config profile.udp.ovpn --persistent
openvpn3 config-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --enable-legacy-algorithms true --show
openvpn3 session-start --config profile.udp.ovpn
openvpn3 sessions-list 
openvpn3 session-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --disconnect
```